# Solve this recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

*Solve the following recursions:
$a_{n+1}=3a_n-a_{n-1}-1$
and
$a_{n+1}=4a_n-a_{n-1}-1$.
(These are to be solved separately, not simultaneously)*

I tried using generating functions but it got messy. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You should add initial values (e.g. $a_0, a_1$) for both recurrence relations in order to completely specify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use difference equations: 
$$
a_n = 3 a_{n-1} -a _{n-2} -1\\
\Delta a_{n+1}  = a_{n+1} - a_n\\
\Delta a_{n+1}  = 3 \Delta a_{n} - \Delta a_{n-1} 
$$
Now for simplicity set $b_n = \Delta a_n$ and use generating function and telescoping sums.

2) same

Comment: This is an (almost) full solution, just look at the first equation I wrote and subtract it form what you have. IF you're familiar with GFs, the rest shouldn't be a problem.